# Passing Link ID with .replace()

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML snippet with inline Javascript, it is a button:

```
<a id="btn_PAYPAL" class="btn" title="Ausw�hlen"     onclick="fillMethodData('methodDataPP',     function(){shopUtils.setIsPlatin(); if(validator.validate('ShopEnterForm')) {document.forms['ShopEnterForm'].document.forms['ShopEnterForm'].action='/shop_pending_paypal.html?linkId=/'.replace()'./'.submit();} return false;}); return false;" href="javascript:{}">
    <div>
        <div class="letsBuyImage"><img class="png" src="<r:static bundle="member_image_shop_enter" key="safetyLock"/>"></div>
        <div class="letsBuyText"><r:value bundle="member_text_shop_enter" key="buttonPayPalFinal"/></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

When the user clicks on the button, a form is validated. The user needs to be redirected to shop_pending_paypal.html + linkId. The LinkID is dynamic and should always be passed as a string replacement. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: Please.. don't use inline javascript. It's so hard to read and it looks terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `replace`, then you would put some kind of placeholder in the string, so that you have something to replace:

```
var frm = document.forms['ShopEnterForm'];
frm.action = '/shop_pending_paypal.html?linkId=###'.replace('###', LinkID);
frm.submit();
```

It seems pointless to use `replace` though, when you can just concatenate the values:

```
frm.action = '/shop_pending_paypal.html?linkId=' + LinkID;
```